# Render JSF Page in backend and save the output to file

Tags: jsf, seam

I am using JSF 1.2 with Seam 2.2.2

And woundering if i can render a page from with in the Code and Save the output to a file instead of sending it to the client.

//Trind

Comment: Sounds like the sound for a Filter if it was for HTML, but I do not know how JSF would handle the current page/bean (would it remove it if it was a ViewScoped bean)?

Comment: or what would the browser do (after all it has send a request and received no reply, although maybe Ajax would ease this).

Comment: I am not sure how i atm even should start to render a page(faclets) from the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way would be just sending a HTTP request yourself (which should be particularly cheap when performing on localhost).

```
InputStream input = new URL("http://localhost:8080/context/page.jsf").openStream();
// ...
```

If you'd like to request it within the same session as the current client and your server accepts URL rewriting, then use the following URL instead.

```
InputStream input = new URL("http://localhost:8080/context/page.jsf;jsessionid=" + session.getId()).openStream();
// ...
```

Or if your server doesn't accept URL rewriting, but accepts cookies only, then use the following approach instead.

```
URLConnection connection = new URL("http://localhost:8080/context/page.jsf").openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "JSESSIONID=" + session.getId());
InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
// ...
```

Comment: Yes, but that's clumsy. I can tell from top of head for JSF 2.x, but not for JSF 1.2 at this moment.

Comment: ah okey, if you have the energy please let me know would appriciate it :)

Comment: @BalusC : When openStream a jsf page , the `preRenderView` event dont called.How i open a jsf page and streaming content of it that `preRenderView` event also called?

Comment: @BalusC : Thanks.I use Spring security. When open desired page ,`openStream` opened my logout url.i added `RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().getSessionId()` to the desired url but it cann't open this url.How can i open my url?

Comment: I used cookies and it worked properly.thanks @BalusC